# GULP cannot find module

Tags: gulp

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require( "gulp" ),
    traceur = require( "traceur" ),
    babel = require( "babel" ),
    plumber = require( "plumber" ),
    es6Path = "es6/*.js",
    compilePath = "es6/compiled";

gulp.task( "traceur", function () {
    gulp.src( [ es6Path ] )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( traceur( { blockBinding: true } ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( compilePath + '/traceur' ) );
});

gulp.task( "babel", function () {
    gulp.src( [ es6Path ] )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( babel() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( compilePath + '/babel' ) );
});

gulp.task( "watch", function() {
    gulp.watch( [ es6Path ], [ "traceur", "babel" ] );
});

gulp.task( "default", [ "traceur", "babel", "watch" ] );
```

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "ES6Demos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Getting started wtih ES6 using gulp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Vinayak Phal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^5.2.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-traceur": "^0.17.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.9.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Installed all the dependencies and everything but still I'm getting the following error.

This is not only with traceur, it gives error for other modules as well.
whichever comes next to gulp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requiring "traceur". You need to require "gulp-traceur". Same thing for the other packages.